SPGO is not populating the workspace
my organization just migrated to SharePoint SE and we are trying to connect via Visual Studio since Sharepoint designer will be deprecated. I created the json file but when I try to populate the workspace it keeps spinning. Our servers are on premises so I chose NTML as the authentication type but when trying to populate the workspace it keeps spinning.
{
    "sourceDirectory": "src",
    "sharePointSiteUrl": "https://bc-net",
    "workspaceRoot": "c:\\Users\\jangelogianopulos\\Desktop\\BCNetSE",
    "publishWorkspaceOptions": {
        "destinationFolder": "/",
        "globPattern": "c:\\Users\\jangelogianopulos\\Desktop\\BCNetSE\\src\\**\\*.*",
        "localRoot": "c:\\Users\\jangelogianopulos\\Desktop\\BCNetSE\\src"
    },
    "publishingScope": "SaveOnly",
    "authenticationType": "NTLM",
    "remoteFolders" :[
        "/_catalogs/masterpage/**/*.*"
    ]
}

